# Big Bank Job - 12 Angry Minutes

Tags: achievements, payday-2

In the Big Bank Job, there is an achievement for accomplishing the entire job in 12 minutes.

**What pre-planning options and actions within the bank are essential to finish this job as per the requirements of the achievement?**

Assume I'm using a group of 4 players, no AI, and we're playing on normal difficulty as I would expect it would be easier to do on this mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Loud, fast, coordinated, and on Hard

I am going to make the following assumptions for this:

- You have 4 players that are familiar with the heist and what Plan B (loud) entails
- That at least two players can consistently get the correct computer for the time-lock on the first try whenever luck isn't severely in your favor. Look up the "It Takes Two To Tango" achievement for specifics on how to do this.
- That you want to do it on the easiest difficulty possible (Which is hard - Normal difficulty is ineligible for the achievement)
- And you want the least amount of headaches (which rules out the fast-and-stealthy approach)

### The Preplanning

The plan you have walking in can make all the difference, and proper asset selection makes it a lot easier to do.

- Escape Plan: You will want the Bus escape (6 favors). It's a safe, fast extraction and if the vault door is in the ideal spot (2F, on the left), that's even less ground that has to be covered.
- Hacking: The Time Lock (2 Favors) is essential as it shaves off 30 seconds on the time-lock. That's a 30-second cushion you get for stuff like the HUGE_LANCE (aka The Beast) breaking.
- Other assets: Some people prefer having the zip-line, others prefer making sure a keycard is available because they don't want to bring ECMs. Your discretion here.

### The Loadout

You will want the following:

- A Saw. Shaped charges can suffice as a backup, but the saw is faster. Seconds will likely matter.
- 2 ECMs, with ECM Overdrive Aced. This is for the two Security Doors that will have to be opened (the Server door and the roof door, more on that later)
- Appropriate Armor. For Ghost builds, a Light Ballistic Vest will probably fare much better than a CTV due to the high dodge. Enforcers may want to take Flak Jacket (or possibly heavier). Note that the ICTV is overkill, especially on Hard.

### The Execution

Stealth is a non-issue here, and maintaining stealth can cause time to be wasted later. The person with ECMs will first locate the server room and open it, hitting the computer (just in case it works - it's rare, but it happens). Then, two people (hopefully NOT including the person with ECMs) will work on the computers while the ECM guy hits the roof and opens the other door to handle the time lock rewiring. Fourth guy will be on the roof, immediately heading to the crane once stealth breaks (the Zip-Line cannot be set beforehand) to start moving Floyd the giant pig into position.

For the two people on computers, once the person at the workstations confirms the correct computer, the server person will move to the time-lock switch to hit it at the earliest moment. Once it is hit, the ECM guy (or whoever's on the roof) will need to rewire the time-lock code, and then the switch will need to be hit a second time. If all goes to plan, Floyd should drop with at least 30 seconds still left on the time lock (60 if you did not buy the corresponding favor), at which point everyone should get a spare part and move the bags to the time lock door. You should, ideally, be through the door around the 4:30 mark (Time Lock takes 3 minutes before favor, factor in about a minute and a half to get it going in the first place).

After that, it is just speedrunning the remainder of the heist and making sure to grab CASH BAGS, not gold bags. You will need 4 bags, or one per player.

Comment: Finding the correct computer involves one player operating the server and another player to look for a blinking monitor in either the upstairs or downstairs office, right?

Comment: Correct. The terminal will also beep, which can help locate it even if you don't quite have line-of-sight to the screen.

Comment: Very helpful post, this looks like a plan I can talk my team into trying.  Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

A recent solution to completing this mission is to use a recently discovered glitch:

Requires elevator trick escape.

Basically, there is a chance that a camera will spawn in the managers corridor (street side) that a play can jump onto using a sprint jump. From there you can jump through the ceiling and across some light fixtures into an area outside the map. You can make you way across to the vault area where you can pickup gold through the walls. There is always (in my experience) 4 bags of gold, allowing the player to grab enough bags to complete the mission.

There is a specific path the play needs to follow around the map, with a couple of sections where the player throws bags into the void to get them to respawn in desired locations (in an inaccessible part of the garage, followed by a respawn next to the van).  After throwing the bags the player follows them in order to get the same respawn.

This gets the player and bags into the bottom garage, where they can activate the elevator doors to enable to loot drop and escape.

It can be done with 4 players, but there is a problem with when the players need to fall into the void to respawn: instead of falling and respawning on the ground they respawn at other players meaning you can get stuck in an infinite fall-respawn loop. Leaving/rejoining is a solution but they you don't get the achievement. The best solution (after practising) is for one player to do everything and for the other players to get themselves downed (falling, police etc) and to go into custody, allowing the main player to complete the mission solo.

It is worth this player being the host, as some strange things happen to the bags with clients, and sometimes they are invisible/in the wrong places for clients.

I did it with my group a few times last night, very doable with a bit of practice.

One handy tool for discovering where you can walk/fall is to either shoot the floor (if there is a surface) or attempt to deploy your equipment. Be careful though, throwing bags off in the wrong locations can cause them to respawn INSIDE the walls and thus unreachable to you/will cause the alarm to go off if you are doing it stealth (you can get on top of the camera and jump outside the map without alerting anyone if you are careful).

Comment: As of today - September 4, 2014 - this no longer works. That particular hole in the collision geometry has been fixed.